# Spot Color shade Implementation in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to manage the Spot Color using the ActionScript 3.0. Spot Color is CMYK based special shading color. it is using for printing purpose.

Does anybody has any idea about the spotcolor and trnasfering to the PHP server side development to create image?

Comment: As far as I know, flash does not natively support any other color space other than rgb. But even more basic than that, I have no idea what you are really asking. What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: I know the RGB supported by Flash. But I want to develop a Spot color panel in Flash for some special Application.

Comment: what do you mean by "spot color", in traditional multi-plate printing you have 4 channels for CMY and K, spot colors are extra plates for specific colors, essentially having 5+ color channels. Flash only supports drawing in the RGB colorspace... Are you asking how to store multi-channel color systems? How to dynamically build `BitmapData` and display it in the stage? How to simulate a subtractive color system in an additive color system like flash? How to transfer data to a server with PHP? There are a bunch of possible ways to answer this, and you are pretty vauge on what you actually need.

Comment: I know the Only RGB Color supported by the Flash development but, I want to know how handle the Spot Color in flash application runtime. So I can give the effect like spot color which is used for Special Printing purpose. I find some resource with AlivePDF and PurePDF library in ActionScript 3.0 for Flash Development. 
I want to display images/Graphics which has spotcolor but with out any color loss or color  shade change.....